# How to remove Ubuntu from SSD or Motherboard?

Tags: server, windows, uninstall, ssd

I have a computer I'm trying to build and I launched Ubuntu with a flashdrive.

Now I want to actually use windows with a usb.

But I'm not sure how to get rid of Ubuntu on my SSD or whatever.

I'm not very techy with code and such so if someone could please help!

Also I don't have an internet connection on Ubuntu computer.

Thanks

Comment: Did you actually install the Ubuntu, or just use it from the Flash drive?

Comment: Remove all partitions on your SSD.  Apply changes, leave it blank with no partitions.  Boot your Windows medium and install using all the SSD - Let Windows decide!!

Comment: If UEFI you have settings in UEFI and ESP - efi system partition. To remove:  Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot the Ubuntu USB flash drive that you have as an Ubuntu live session.
2. Open the GParted application and reformat the SSD to remove Ubuntu from the SSD. This will overwrite all the files that are on the SSD. If you are planning to ever install Windows on that SSD, please note that Windows requires NTFS format for the file system.
3. Now you can install Windows however you want.